# how to achieve matplotlib radial gradient background

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to get matplotlib background as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ticks = ["Low", "Moderate", "High"]
plt.xlabel(r"x $\longrightarrow$", fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel(r"y $\longrightarrow$", fontsize=14)
plotlim = plt.xlim() + plt.ylim()
print(plotlim)
ax.imshow([[1, 1], [0, 0]],
          cmap=plt.cm.Reds,
          interpolation='bicubic',
          extent=plotlim)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(ticks)) / 2, ticks, fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(ticks)) / 2,
           ticks,
           rotation='90',
           ha='center',
           fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

Problem is this is giving the gradient along `y-axis`, while I want a radial gradient, something like: [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need to adjust the matrix that you are interpolating such that the gradient in that matrix is pointing to the uppper right corner:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ticks = ["Low", "Moderate", "High"]
plt.xlabel(r"x $\longrightarrow$", fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel(r"y $\longrightarrow$", fontsize=14)
plotlim = plt.xlim() + plt.ylim()
print(plotlim)
ax.imshow([[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0, 0.5, 0.5], [0, 0, 0.5]],
          cmap=plt.cm.Reds,
          interpolation='bicubic',
          extent=plotlim, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(ticks)) / 2, ticks, fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(ticks)) / 2,
           ticks,
           rotation='90',
           ha='center',
           fontsize=14)

fig.savefig("test.png")
```

This give the following picture:

[image]

EDIT:

You can also build up the gradient without interpolation to get a nice circular gradient:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 256)
y = np.linspace(1, 0, 256)

xArray, yArray = np.meshgrid(x, y)
plotArray = np.sqrt(xArray**2 + yArray**2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(plotArray,
          cmap=plt.cm.Reds,
          vmin=0,
          vmax=1)
```

[image]